# About a proof of $\lvert \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \rvert = \aleph$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am reading "A Course in Analysis vol.3" written by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

There is the following exercise in this book:

> P.37 Exercise 13
>
> Let $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets with $\lvert I \rvert = \aleph = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$.
>
> Assume $|X_i| = \aleph = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$ for all $i \in I$.
>
> Prove that $\lvert \displaystyle \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \rvert = \aleph = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$.

In the solution of this exercise, the author writes that "We can assume that $X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$ without loss of generality".

I cannot understand why we can assume that $X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$ without loss of generality.

Comment: What is the cardinality of $I$

Comment: Lets consider the extreme cases: If $X_i=X_j$ for all $i,j \in I$ then $|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i|=|X_z|=\aleph_0$ for an arbitrary $z \in I$.  In the other case they are all completely distinct, then $|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i| = \aleph_0 + \aleph_0 + ...$ in other words, a countably infinite sum of cardinalities $\aleph_0$ which is just $\aleph_0$ added to itself $\aleph_0$ many times, i.e. $|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i| = \aleph_0 \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.  Thus all the intermediate cases fall within the two extremes.

Comment: What does $\aleph$ mean?

Comment: $\aleph = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$

Comment: The cardinality of $I$ is $\aleph = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$.

Comment: When the author writes "We can assume that $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ for $i\ne j$ without loss of generality" he means that, if we can prove the result with the help of that extra assumption, then we can also prove it without the extra assumption. I suppose what he has in mind is the fact that, given any sets $(X_i)_{i\in I},$ we can find sets $(X'_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $X'_i\cap X'_j=\emptyset$ for $i\ne j,$ and $\bigcup_{i\in I}X'_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i.$ That can be proved easily using the axiom of choice. Have you had the axiom of choice?

Comment: the aleph without a subcript is not standard notation.